# How to do likelihood ratio test to compare two panel models (plm) in R

Tags: r, panel-data, likelihood-ratio, plm

I have a problem to run a likelihood ratio test to compare two panel regression models in order to find whether one model is significantly better than the another one. However, neither lrtest nor anova functions can be applied to 'plm' class. Due to the limit of my statistic knowledge, I failed to understand the likehihood ratio test formula and thus would like to ask for help to solve this problem.

Sample code could be:

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")
mod1 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
mod2 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
#However, anova(mod1, mod2) or lrtest(mod1, mod2) will report a error
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, `plm` is a linear model and I think it is OLS estimation not maximum likelihood.  If that's right, you have no likelihood to test in that way.

If it is OLS-based, you could compare the adjusted R-squared and use the better one, provided your model assumptions hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask is there any way to compare two panel models to find a significantly better one? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `plm::pFtest(mod1, mod2)`

Comment: Thanks! However, the pFtest cannot compare e.g. two fixed effect models, pFtest requires one model to be a pooling model.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The documentation says it is to compare to a pooling model, but you can really put arbitrary models in there to get an F test.

Answer (score 1):

The test amounts to testing if including `log(emp)` should additionally enter the model over and above the variables already contained in `mod2`. That can be done with a conventional t-test (so just look at the model summary output in R).

I am not really sure what kind of "story" that hypothesis test is to capture, though, given that you already have `unemp` in the model - what is the rationale behind including both log employment (I suppose) and unemployment?